# Does Android App debug uses more memory than regular app?

Tags: android, heap-memory, android-memory

I am creating an App in Android Studio and when testing it on my device (running it through Android Studio Shift+ F10) and monitoring the memory usage I see that it says `Allocated 25MB`. When I go to App info to see the memory usage it says 60 MB in the past 3 hours, Max of 130 MB.

I think that is extremely high, is it because the app is in debug stage? or I should investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Well...there are many ways to detect this and to make your app uses less memory...check on this link and follow their tips:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html

But if you just want a fast check, you can open task manager or do top for that process id. Considering you can't lighten up the app try to close all other heavy weight application whilst your debugging.